# customizing virtualTree in qooxdoo doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I'm using qooxdoo to build a custom virtualTree, which works fine as expected until I open/close/reopen a node.
It's a mess then. I don't know which part I'm missing.

here's a code sample:
[virtual tree](http://www.qooxdoo.org)

To reproduce, please open a node (for example "Dep1"). You can hover childrens and everything is fine. Now close the node and reopen it. Now icons get changed in node and node receives the hover effect, which is not the case when we initially opened it.

Am I missing something?

Regards

code below:

```js
var data = {
 "label": "ROOT",
 
 "children" : [
    {
      "LDEP" : "Dep1",
      "children" : [
        {
          "CVEH" : 1,
          "LVEH" : "veh1_1"
        },
        {
          "CVEH" : 2,
          "LVEH" : "veh1_2"
        }
      ]
    },
    
    {
      "LDEP" : "Dep2",
      "children" : [
        {
          "CVEH" : 3,
          "LVEH" : "veh2_1"
        },
        {
          "CVEH" : 4,
          "LVEH" : "veh2_2"
        }
      ]
    },
    
  ]
  
};
var model = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel(data, false);
var vtree = new qx.ui.tree.VirtualTree(model, "children", "children");

this.getRoot().add(vtree,
{
  left : 100,
  right : 100,
  top  : 50
});

vtree.set({
 showTopLevelOpenCloseIcons : true,
 hideRoot : true,
 backgroundColor : "gray"
});
   
/* label options */
vtree.setLabelOptions({
    converter : function(value, model)
    {
     if (value){ 
      return  "<b>" + model.get("LDEP") + "</b>";
     }
     else
     { 
      return model.get("LVEH");
     }
    }
});
       

/* 
 * icon options, if a dep then return a generic symbol else return 
 * vehicle icon
 */
vtree.setIconPath("children");
vtree.setIconOptions({
  converter : function(value, model)
  {
   if (value){
    return "icon/22/mimetypes/text-html.png";
   }
   else
   { 
    return "icon/22/mimetypes/media-image.png"
   }
  }
});


var delegate = {
    bindItem : function(controller, item, index)
    {
      controller.bindDefaultProperties(item, index);
      
      //set icon size to 24x24 for leaves
      var icon = item.getChildControl("icon");
      if(item.getModel().getChildren){
       //dept
       item.setBackgroundColor("gray");
      } else {
       //vehicle
       item.setBackgroundColor("white");
       icon.set({
        width  : 32,
        height  : 32,
        scale : true,
        marginTop : -4
       });
      }
  
      //labels, accept html
      var lbl = item.getChildControl("label");
      lbl.set({
       rich : true,
       textColor : "black"
      });
  
      //change color on pointerin and pointerout of vehicles
      if (!item.getModel().getChildren){
       item.addListener("pointerover", function(){
        item.getChildControl("label").fadeIn(100);
        item.setBackgroundColor("blue");
        item.getChildControl("label").setTextColor("orange");
       });
       
       item.addListener("pointerout", function(){
        item.setBackgroundColor("white");
        item.getChildControl("label").setTextColor("black");
       });
      }
    },
    
    /* 
     * sorting
     */ 
    sorter : function(a, b){
     var A = (a.getChildren? a.get("LDEP") : a.get("LVEH")).toUpperCase(), 
        B = (b.getChildren? b.get("LDEP") : b.get("LVEH")).toUpperCase(); 
      
     return A > B ? 1 : A < B ? -1 : 0; 
    }
};
  
vtree.setDelegate(delegate);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the effects you are observing, it needs understanding on how virtual widgets work in qooxdoo.

Virtual widget means that you are able do display huge amounts of data, only having a few widgets rendering the visible content. Imagine a tree with hundreds of nodes and child nodes, but you only have 10 nodes visible at one time. The virtual widget then instantiates as many real widgets as needed and re-uses those widgets to display the visible part of the tree.

The virtual tree widget, which diplays nodes an leaves of a tree, reuses the instantiated widgets by changing the model of the widget and it's appearance. This way it may happen that on user interaction, a virtual tree node is rendered by an item which formely displayed a leafe.

All this is done via the delegates `bindItem` member function which is called every time a real widget is re-used for a virtual item. So adding an event listener in `bindItem` adds subsequent more and more event listeners to a single widget tree/leaf instance, showing the effects you described.

To achieve what you want, you have to add your logic into the `configureItem` delegate member, which is only called once on instantiation of a tree item widget. There you have to differentiate between the item currently displaying a node or a leaf which you can simply accomplish by getting the current appearance of that item via `item.getAppearance()`. The result will be either `virtual-tree-file` for a leaf and `virtual-tree-folder` for a node.

The event listeners which are added for `pointerover` and `pointerout` should then add the styles needed depending on the appearance.

Note all this should better be handeled by a custom appearance theme, where you could add most styles you used based on the widgets states like hover, besides the animation for the label child control with the fading in label.

Please paste the following gist into the qooxdoo playground where I've created an example which demonstrates all the speech above:

https://gist.github.com/level420/ba4e25f98618064f91f5aa6cb6bb1124

Comment: thank you very much, first for the long and clear explanation, second for the example which works like a charm.
BTW I've started writing configureItem but wasn't quite sure if it's the way to go, so after days of testings I decided to post here.
Working with themes is another story, I'm eager to learn it, but still didn't have enough time to dig into.
Thank you again.